# Recurrence relation for Legendre polynomials

Tags: calculus

show that 
$$(n+1)p_{n+1} (x) = (2n+1)xp_{n} (x)-np_{n-1} (x) $$
attempting the problem above,
from Rodrigues' formula 
$$(n+1)p_{n+1} (x) = n+1 \frac{1}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!} \frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}} (x^2-1)^n $$ 
$$(n+1)p_{n+1} (x) =  \frac{1}{2^{n+1}n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} n(x^2-1)^{n-1}2x $$ 
$$(n+1)p_{n+1} (x) =  \frac{1}{2^{n}n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} 2nx(x^2-1)^{n-1} $$ 
   $$ =  \frac{1}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!} d\frac{d^n}{dx^n} 2(n+1)x(x^2-1)^{n} $$ 
put n=n+1
    $$ =  \frac{1}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!} d\frac{d^n}{dx^n} (2n+2)x(x^2-1)^{n} $$

am trying to joggle the equation to be able to arrive at the solution. Before posting this, i have thought of many ways i could arrive at the solution but to no avail. pls help out!

Answer (score 1):

Try this link. It explains the solution using a generating function approach
http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/math335s112/notes/Recurrence%20relation%20Pn(x).pdf
Using the Rodrigues formula might get a bit cumbersome.

Comment: No problemo. Always Happy.